# Regex to match sentence that contains specific word under a specific heading

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

Example Text:

**JAVA**

100 Programmer

101 Unary operator is used 
    everywhere in the world.

**.NET**

200 Silver Light is the best
    way to get the application

201 Windows applications

---

When I give input to program
'JAVA' and '101'. It should match as true. Since, 101 is present under the heading - JAVA.

But, when I give input as
'JAVA' and '200'. It should say false. Since, 200 is not present under the heading JAVA.

Here is the regex used :

```
String code = "JAVA";
String string = "100 Programmer"

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("" + 
escapeString(code) + "((?![\\t][A-Z\\s ]).)*" + escapeString(string) + "", Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(doc);

boolean isFound = matcher.find();
System.out.println(isFound);


String escapeString(String string) {
String escaped = null;
if (null !== string) {
   escaped = Pattern.quote(string);
}
return escaped;
}
```

Can anyone please give regex for this?

Comment: What format is your "Example Text"? How do you define a heading?

Comment: Are you looking to only match 'JAVA' with '101' or '100', and only match '.NET' with '200' or '201'?

Comment: How far have you got with this?  Please post your code so far, including your own regex.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JacobBoertjes  Yes, so that when i give input as "JAVA" and  101. It means 101 comes under that heading.

Comment: @Archer code posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should declare how did you code the headings and the values under each header? 
I think the answer starts from this point, how did you group the headers. 
If you store the values under each header in a string then this regex should work correctly:

```
String JavaHeader = "100 Programmer";
boolean exists = JavaHeader.matches("100.*")
```